# Nestjs many to many relationship api design

Tags: rest, many-to-many, nestjs

I have two entities, Student and Course. A student can enroll in many courses and a course can have many students.
I want to save the grade of each student in each course, so I named the junction table Assessment and created an assessment resource with nestjs cli.

The API have the following use cases

1. Get all grades of a course
2. Get grades of a student in the enrolled courses
3. Enroll a student in a course

Therefore, I have the following API routes

1. GET /api/courses/grades
2. GET /api/students/courses
3. POST /api/courses/:id/students

The problem is, the above three routes are nested in the courses and students resource controller. The CRUD of the assessment resource is unused. So, should I put the routes in the assessment resource or the above implementation is better?

In general, the junction table in many to many relationship should not be a resource in. nestjs? Because all the operation can be done in the resource of the "many" sides. Is there any examples where the junction table has its own CRUD?

Thank you, I am sorry if it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you. But in nestjs world we have **nest-router** package https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-router. So you could create a children's routes. Сheck out examples in readme of this package.
Or another approach that I saw it's *flat* endpoits. For example:

```
GET /api/grades?course=couseId
```